# Listener bounded to model attribute not triggering

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Here's the code in CoffeeScript:

```
class this.User extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: -> 
    @access_token
    @cur_video_id_playing
    @logged_in = 0
    @username
    this.bind "change:username", () -> alert this.get(username) 

this.user = new User;
```

When I'm in the developer console and call

```
user.username = "newname"
```

The alert doesn't trigger. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to use [`Model::set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set):

```
user.set 'username', 'newname'
```

Or, using an object literal:

```
user.set username: 'newname'
```

The username will actually be stored in `user.attributes.username`. In your change listener, you should access the username using [`Model::get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get); something like:

```
@on 'change:username', -> alert @get 'username'
```